# How to compare two Persian date via Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, persian

I have a table as follow in oracle 11g:

```
Persons Table:
|ID      |FirstName|LastName|PersianBirthDate|
|1       |FName1   |LName1  |"1362/01/01"    |
|2       |FName2   |LName2  |"1359/05/01"    |
|3       |FName3   |LName3  |"1350/04/11"    |
|4       |FName4   |LName4  |"1355/02/10"    |
|5       |FName5   |LName1  |"1365/12/25"    |
```

When i want to get rows that their `PersianDateBirthDate` are less than `"1362/01/01"` like as below:

```
|ID      |FirstName|LastName|PersianBirthDate|
|2       |FName2   |LName2  |"1359/05/01"    |
|3       |FName3   |LName3  |"1350/04/11"    |
|4       |FName4   |LName4  |"1355/02/10"    |
```

I use following code in EntityFramework (code-first):

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
  return (db.Persons
            .Where(x=>
                      PersianDateTime.Parse(x.PersianBirthDate).ToDateTime()
                      < PersianDateTime.Parse("1362/01/01").ToDateTime())
            .ToList();
}
```

But the following exception occurs:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I can't use `db.persons.AsEnumerable()`.

Note: The datatype of **PersianBirthDate** is `char(10)` and 
`PersianDateTime` library convert **Persian Date** to **Gregorian Date**.

Comment: `The datatype of PersianBirthDate is char(10)`.  That's your problem.  Fix that by changing the database column to be an actual date field.

Comment: I cannot change the datatype of PersianBirthDate. :(

Comment: Since the string contain year, month, day in that order, do a string comparison instead. Compare the stored string to a client-side formatted string containing a Persian date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @KristoferA comment, we can use code below:

```
db.Persons
  .Where(x => x.PersianBirthDate.CompareTo("1362/01/01") < 0).ToList();
```

And then the following SQL is sent to DB:

```
 SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[PersianBirthDate] AS [PersianBirthDate]
FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PersianBirthDate] < N'1362/01/01'
```

But I think, We can improve this solution.

Comment: The another answer will be appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
p.Where(x => ((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(0,4)) < year) || 
             (((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(0,4)) = year) && ((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(5,2) < month)) ||
             (((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(0,4)) = year) && ((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(5,2) = month)  && ((int)x.PersianBirthDate.Substring(8,2) <= day)
```

Comment: Unless the EF adapter for Oracle is truly amazing, this will not work - there is no SQL equivalent most of the things in your query.

Comment: @SteveRuble This is not EF -- just linq.

Comment: @Hogan: ERROR: `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree` raised!

Comment: @Hogan, then it's not an answer to this question, is it?

Comment: @Hogan: Your answer is correct for linq-to-objects not for linq-to-entities, this query not executed on db(for example: oracle) with EntityFramework(code-first).

Comment: @Amir - right, it is easy to switch from entities to objects to solve the problem, if you want it to run faster at the db tier I suggest create a view or SP.

Comment: @Hogan The question itself specifically said it wasn't an option to pull the entire database table into memory.